# Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.19 (port 19000) from /192.168.0.4 (port 42644) after 10000ms

Tags: react-native, expo

Estoy tratando de ejecutar un programa de expo en mi celular android desde ExpoGo pero al escanear el codigo qr me tira este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente cambiando la direccion ip y conectando mi celular en el modo de depuracion asi como lo menciona aqui: https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app/issues/876

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.